# pip install pyemd error?

Tags: python, nlp, pip, gensim

I'm trying to install `pyemd` package in Python through `pip` and getting following error:

```
C:\Users\dipanwita.neogy>pip install pyemd
Collecting pyemd
  Using cached pyemd-0.4.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0.0,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\dipanwita.neogy\a
naconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyemd)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyemd
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyemd ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\dipanwita.neogy\Anaconda3\python.exe -u
-c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DIPANW~1.NEO\\AppData\\Loca
l\\Temp\\pip-build-nk13uh5b\\pyemd\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(
__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __fil
e__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\DIPANW~1.NEO\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpngn2np
rmpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyemd
  copying pyemd\__about__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyemd
  copying pyemd\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyemd
  running build_ext
  building 'pyemd.emd' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C+
+ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyemd
  Running setup.py clean for pyemd
Failed to build pyemd
Installing collected packages: pyemd
  Running setup.py install for pyemd ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\dipanwita.neogy\Anaconda3\python.exe -
u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DIPANW~1.NEO\\AppData\\Lo
cal\\Temp\\pip-build-nk13uh5b\\pyemd\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open
)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __f
ile__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DIPANW~1.NEO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-e
rihhtfj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyemd
    copying pyemd\__about__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyemd
    copying pyemd\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyemd
    running build_ext
    building 'pyemd.emd' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual
C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\dipanwita.neogy\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
 tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DIPANW~1.NEO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-nk1
3uh5b\\pyemd\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read(
).replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
 --record C:\Users\DIPANW~1.NEO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-erihhtfj-record\install-r
ecord.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code
1 in C:\Users\DIPANW~1.NEO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nk13uh5b\pyemd\
```

I cannot find anything regarding this error. Please suggest me what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are receiving is: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools`. You need to read the error message carefully.

You just need to go to the link they have provided for you and follow the instructions: http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Answer (score 1):

Following below steps helped me overcome the error:

1. While **installing the Visual Studio**: [Download Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16)

   - ->  `Desktop development with C++`
   - -> **Check** `C++/CLI support for v142 build tools (14.24)`
2. **Having the below dependency** ready:

   - get Python --Version in CLI.
   - Download and install whl file from [Twisted WHL file](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted)
   - pip install C:\"Twisted‑19.10.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl"
3. **Finally Run**:

   - pip install -v pyemd